# Joint probability distribution using differential algebra

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, differential-forms

I came across [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36093/construction-of-dirichlet-distribution-with-gamma-distribution/154298#154298) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180715/multivariate-transformation-of-random-variable/180757#180757) answers explaning how to compute joint probability distribution by using differential forms, which I think it is an elegant method to deal with this kind of problem.
I have tried to apply this approach to the following problem:

Let $U,V$ be normally distributed random variables and $W$ be uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$.

Let also two other continuous dependent variables $X$ and $Y$ given by

$$X=U+W  ~~~~ \text{and} ~~~~ Y=V+W.$$

> I want to compute the joint probability distribution $f_{XY}(x,y)$ from $f_{UV}(u,v)$ and $f_W(w)$.

**My thoughts:**

First, I compute the wedge product
$$dx \wedge dy = (du+dw)\wedge(dv+dw) = du\wedge dv+du\wedge dw+dw\wedge dv$$

However, when I write the probability element
$$ f_{XY}(x,y)|dx \wedge dy|, $$

I have no idea how to proceed from this

$$|dx \wedge dy| = |du\wedge dv+du\wedge dw+dw\wedge dv|. $$

I appreciate any help!

---

**EDIT:**

I think I have got the solution but I am not sure if it is correct.
I created a new variable $Z=W$. This allows me to write the differential element $|dx\wedge dy \wedge dz|$ as a three-form $g(u,v,w)|du\wedge dv \wedge dw|.$ Thus,

$$ dx\,dy\,dz=|dx\wedge dy \wedge dz| =|(du+dw)\wedge (dv+dw)\wedge dw| = |du\wedge dv\wedge dw|=du\,dv\,dw.$$

Therefore, the joint probability element $f_{XYZ}(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz$ is given by

$$f_{XYZ}(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz = f_{UVW}(u,v,w)\,du\,dv\,dw \implies f_{XYZ}(x,y,z) = f_{UVW}(x-z,y-z,z) = f_{UV}(x-z,y-z)f_{W}(z),$$ and

$$f_{XY}(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{XYZ}(x,y,z)\,dz = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{UV}(x-z,y-z)f_{W}(z)\,dz = \int_{0}^{1}f_{UV}(x-z,y-z)\,dz.$$

Is my solution correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Indeed, computing the distribution of (X,Y,W) and then integrating with respect to the third coordinate, is the simplest approach, requiring only the [Jacobian change of variables formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) for integrals in its basest form. Elegant or not, this is ultra classical (and taught as such in uncountably many courses).

Comment: @Did, Jacobian approach is indeed classical, but it requires the computation of a determinant. In my case it is not complicated, because the functions of variables are very simple. I discuss about another approach: differential forms. It seems to be very attractive and elegant (imao) because we avoid computing the determinant of the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: What you call the differential form approach is strictly equivalent to the computation of the Jacobian determinant, only, the formalism of differential forms makes that you fail to see it. If you wonder how one computes the term in front of the elementary differential form, you should soon see it as a determinant...

Comment: @Did, I agree. Thanks.